# How to parse an String xml to return all the traversal paths using Java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax, stax

I am trying to parse an xml String to return all the traversal paths from root to depth.
Please help to meet my requirement.

My xml String is as below:

```
<levels>
    <level>
        <id>123</id>
        <name>Leave Review by Manager</name>
        <task>Review by Manager</task>
        <clauses>
            <clause>
                <id>123</id>
                <name>Leave Review By Manager</name>
                <role>123</role>
                <users>
                    <user>
                        <id>abcd@xyz.com</id>
                        <name>ABC D</name>
                    </user>
                </users>
                <actions>
                    <action>
                        <id>123</id>
                        <name>Approved</name>
                        <type>Accepted</type>
                        <caption>Approve</caption>
                        <level />
                    </action>
                    <action>
                        <id>123</id>
                        <name>Rejected by Manager</name>
                        <type>Rejected</type>
                        <caption>Reject</caption>
                        <level />
                    </action>
                </actions>
            </clause>
        </clauses>
    </level>
</levels>
```

Expected Output: Return all the traversal Paths in the form of HashMap or List type

```
levelId="123",  levelName="Leave Review by Manager",    taskName="Review by Manager",   clauseId="123", clauseName="Leave Review By Manager", clauseRole="123", userId="abc.d@xyz.com", userName="ABC D"    actionId="123", actionName="Approved", actionType="Accepted", actionCaption="Approve"

levelId="123",  levelName="Leave Review by Manager",    taskName="Review by Manager",   clauseId="123", clauseName="Leave Review By Manager", clauseRole="123", userId="abc.d@xyz.com", userName="ABC D"    actionId="123", actionName="Rejected by Manager", actionType="Rejected", actionCaption="Reject"
```

I googled and made the below attempt, but did not get the expected above output:

```
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String levelName = "";
    String actionType = "";
    String actionCaption = "";
    String userId = "";
    String actionName = "";

    try {
        XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        while(xmlEventReader.hasNext()){
            XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
           if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()){
               StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
               if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("level")){

                   //Get the 'levelName' attribute from level element
                   Attribute idAttr = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("name"));
                   if(idAttr != null){
                 levelName = xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData();
                   }
               }
               //set the other varibles from xml elements
               else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("type")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                 actionType = (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("name")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                  actionName = (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("caption")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                   actionCaption = (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("id")){
                   xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                  userId = (xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
               }
           }
           //if level end element is reached, add all strings to list
           if(xmlEvent.isEndElement()){
               EndElement endElement = xmlEvent.asEndElement();
               if(endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("level")){
                   list.addAll(Arrays.asList(levelName, actionType, actionName, actionCaption, userId));
               }
           }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
```

I am getting Output as below:

```
Accepted
Approved
Approve
123

Rejected
Rejected by Manager
Reject
123

Rejected
Rejected by Manager
Reject
123
```

Comment: Have a look at the StAX tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html

Comment: How does the current output look like?

Comment: Hi.. Please help me to find the solution..